# Filling DataTable from DataAdapter - the wrong column is selected as primary key

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, datatable, dataadapter

I am filling a `datatable` object through a `dataadapter` pulling data from a `MS-SQL` database. For some reason the wrong column is set as the primary key on the datatable. I have tried `FillSchema` and `MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey` to no avail.

The correct primary key is defined properly in the SQL server DB schema & is backed by a non clustered unique index `PK_x`.

The column selected as the primary key by the dataadapter is a unique column backed by a clustered unique index.

These are the only two columns in the table.

How does DataAdapter retrieve the table schema from SQL? I have interrogated the sys tables (sys.tables, sys.index_columns, sys.indexes) and they indicate the proper primary key schema. What gives?

Comment: You're going to have to post your code for us to help.

Comment: Have you used DataAdpater.FillSchema(dataset, SchemaType.Source, "Table") ?

Comment: I have tried calling FillSchema in that way.

@Mike I am calling instanceOfDataAdapter.Fill(instanceOfDataTable);
where the data adapter has been given a SQL string to retrieve the rows. The result, regardless of the use of the methods mentioned above is the same; the second of the two columns is selected as a primary key for the data table. The first column is explicitly defined as the primary key of the SQL table. Though both are constrained to be unique (effectively a composite key), only the first column is defined as the primary key.

Comment: And what does the SQL statement look like? It would really be beneficial if you could just drop in a code snippet. The reason for that is because it gives us context to understand what's being sent to the database and what .NET is being forced to interpret.

Comment: @Mike
The select command is just `select * from tableName`
I'm then calling `sourceAdapter.Fill(sourceTable);`

Comment: And the PK is a *single column* in the database? What's the database schema look like? Maybe you could post that since it's only a couple of columns.

Comment: Have you tried running a profiler trace on the db during the call? What if you did CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect; CommandText="TableName"; then Fill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If a unique clustered index is defined on a column or columns in a SQL Server table and the primary key constraint is defined on a separate set of columns, then the names of the columns in the clustered index will be returned. To return the name or names of the primary key columns, use a query hint with the SELECT statement that specifies the name of the primary key index. For more information about specifying query hints, see [Query Hint (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181714.aspx)."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/152bda9x(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx